# Convert to Pointfree Style?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads) discusses "Making a Monad" with the following `Prob` type:

```
import Data.Ratio

newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a,Rational)] } deriving Show
```

`Prob` represents an `a` type, and then a `Rational` representing the probability of this `a` being used.

Let's look at a `Prob` instance:

```
*Main> Prob [('a', 1%2), ('b', 1%2)]
Prob {getProb = [('a',1 % 2),('b',1 % 2)]}
```

LYAH poses an exercise to figure out how to turn `thisSituation`, of type `Prob(Prob Char)` into `Prob Char`:

```
thisSituation :: Prob (Prob Char)
thisSituation = Prob
  [( Prob [('a', 1%2),('b',1%2)], 1%4)
  ,( Prob [('c', 1%2),('d',1%2)], 3%4)
  ]
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a
flatten pp = Prob $ convert $ getProb pp

convert :: [(Prob a, Rational)] -> [(a, Rational)]
convert xs = concat $ map f xs

f :: (Prob a, Rational) -> [(a, Rational)]
f (p, r) = map (mult r) (getProb p)

mult :: Rational -> (a, Rational) -> (a, Rational)
mult r (x, y) = (x, r*y)
```

I tried `point-free` as so:

```
flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a
flatten = Prob $ convert $ getProb
```

But got this error:

```
*Main> :l MakingMonad.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( MakingMonad.hs, interpreted )

MakingMonad.hs:37:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a'
                with actual type `Prob a0'
    In the expression: Prob $ convert $ getProb
    In an equation for `flatten': flatten = Prob $ convert $ getProb

MakingMonad.hs:37:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `[(Prob a0, Rational)]'
                with actual type `Prob a1 -> [(a1, Rational)]'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `getProb'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `convert $ getProb'
    In the expression: Prob $ convert $ getProb
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can I make `flatten` point-free? If so, please show me how. If not, please explain why.

Comment: Change `$` to `.` in `flatten`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `$` in `flatten`, you get code that looks like

```
flatten = Prob $ convert $ getProb
==> Prob (convert (getProb))
```

Which is not what you want.

You want `Prob . convert . getProb`

Comment: so, if I understand, since `getProb` is nested within `Prob(convert(`, it's not possible to use point-free style? But, with function composition, it's possible

Comment: @KevinMeredith When you write `Prob (convert getProb)`, you are passing `(convert getProb)` into `Prob` as an argument. `Prob` doesn't take functions as arguments, `convert` doesn't take functions as arguments either, so you are getting the type errors.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why `f . g . h $ x` style is often preferred instead of `f $ g $ h x` - easier to convert to and from pointfree style.